# SQL, choose column depending on other column

Tags: sql

For school project I wrote a UFC database. I don't know how to write a few queries.
One table is about fight

```
FIGHT:


 - Id_fight, integer, PK
 - Fighter1, integer, FK
 - Fighter2, integer, FK
 - Judge, integer, FK
 - WhichGala, integer, FK
 - HowManyRounds, integer
 - WhoWon, integer
 - HowWon, varchar2(50)
```

To know who won I created a column WhoWon, which can be 1 (fighter1 won), or 2 (fighter2 won). I want to create a few queries, but I don't know how to get the winner of the fight.

Query:
- Show all winners, from every fight ever, without repetition.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? As it is a school project I am assuming either MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: Add sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use case:

```
select distinct -- removes the duplicates
         case when WhoWon = 1 then Fighter1
              when WhoWon = 2 then Fighter2
              else 'Tied fight'
         end as Winners
from Mytable
```

You can also count how many they won:

```
select Winners, count(*) as fightswon
from
(
    select   case when WhoWon = 1 then Fighter1
                  when WhoWon = 2 then Fighter2
                  else 'Tied fight'
             end as Winners, ID_FIGHT
    from Mytable
)
-- Add any joins or where clauses here
group by Winners
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question. What if I would like to show information about fighters who won. How to use your query in subquery? I would like to connect them WHERE fighter.id_fighter = (your query)
Could you help me with this?